# How to paste data to pastebin using the api in php?

Tags: php, curl, http-post, pastebin

```
<?php 

/* gets the data from a URL */ 
function get_data($url) 

{ 

  $ch = curl_init();

  $timeout = 5;

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;

}
$paste_data=""; if(isset($_POST["paste_code"])) { $paste_data = $_POST["paste_code"]; }
echo $paste_data;
$returned_content = get_data('http://pastebin.com/api_public.php/paste_code(paste_data)');
echo $returned_content;
?>
```

This is my php code . where $paste_data contains the data to be pasted in a new page . How do I paste it using the function paste_code(String) ?

Comment: don't know too much about curl, but keep in mind it has to be a `POST` request to `http://pastebin.com/api_public.php` with the variable `paste_code` set. doesn't look you've passed the paste code, nor set the correct parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://pastebin.com/api.php) says that you need to submit a `POST` request to

```
http://pastebin.com/api_public.php
```

and the only mandatory parameter is `paste_code`, of type string is the paste that you want to make.

On success a new `pastebin` URL will be returned.

Bare bone example:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://pastebin.com/api_public.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// A new paste with the string "hello there SO"
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "paste_code=hello there SO");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

and on running I get:

```
> POST http://pastebin.com/api_public.php HTTP/1.1
Host: pastebin.com
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 25
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 13 Dec 2010 07:51:12 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Server: nginx/0.8.52
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.4-dev
< Via: 1.1 apac-nc06 (NetCache NetApp/6.0.6)
< 
http://pastebin.com/Lc7kAw8Z* Closing connection #0
```

Clearly the response has the URL http://pastebin.com/Lc7kAw8Z

Visit it and you'll see a new paste containing `hello there SO`

Answer (score 1):

FYI for others looking at this "post 2013", the api_public.php POST has been discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumple upon this thread via seach, here is a code that works in 2013:

```
<?php
$data = 'Hello World!';

$apiKey = 'xxxxxxx'; // get it from pastebin.com

$postData = array(
    'api_dev_key'           => $apiKey,             // your dev key
    'api_option'            => 'paste',             // action to perform
    'api_paste_code'        => utf8_decode($data),  // the paste text
    'api_paste_private'     => '1',                 // 0=public 1=unlisted 2=private
    'api_paste_expire_date' => '1D',                // paste expires in 1 day
);

$ch = curl_init('http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postData),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
));
$re = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$pasteId = end(explode('/', $re));
echo "Created new paste.\r\n Link:\t{$re}\r\n Raw:\t" . sprintf('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=%s', $pasteId) . "\r\n";
```